# the best way to make a flatList by iterating over a single object array with different key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

what's the best way to make a flatList by iterating over a single object array with different key-value pairs

example:

```
[
  {
    "boteria_chat_aht": "33:55:31",
    "boteria_chat_queue": 2,
    "boteria_chat_tm1r": "00:00:00",
    "boteria_chat_tmr": "00:00:00",
    "boteria_current_chats": 2,
    "boteria_finished_session_percentage": 71.43,
    "boteria_sessions": 7,
    "fbmessenger_chat_aht": "00:00:00",
    "fbmessenger_chat_queue": 0,
    "fbmessenger_chat_tm1r": "00:00:00",
    "fbmessenger_chat_tmr": "00:00:00",
    "fbmessenger_current_chats": 0,
    "fbmessenger_finished_session_percentage": 0,
    "fbmessenger_sessions": 0,
    "inbound_abandoned": 0,
    "inbound_aht": "00:00:00",
    "inbound_asa": "00:00:00",
    "inbound_handled": 0,
    "inbound_queue": 0,
    "inbound_received": 0,
    "mercadolivreperguntas_chat_aht": "00:00:00",
    "mercadolivreperguntas_chat_queue": 0,
    "mercadolivreperguntas_chat_tm1r": "00:00:00",
    "mercadolivreperguntas_chat_tmr": "00:00:00",
    "mercadolivreperguntas_current_chats": 0,
    "mercadolivreperguntas_finished_session_percentage": 0,
    "mercadolivreperguntas_sessions": 0,
    "mercadolivreposvenda_chat_aht": "00:00:00",
    "mercadolivreposvenda_chat_queue": 0,
    "mercadolivreposvenda_chat_tm1r": "00:00:00",
    "mercadolivreposvenda_chat_tmr": "00:00:00",
    "mercadolivreposvenda_current_chats": 0,
    "mercadolivreposvenda_finished_session_percentage": 0,
    "mercadolivreposvenda_sessions": 0,
    "sla": 0,
    "telegram_chat_aht": "00:00:00",
    "telegram_chat_queue": 0,
    "telegram_chat_tm1r": "00:00:00",
    "telegram_chat_tmr": "00:00:00",
    "telegram_current_chats": 0,
    "telegram_finished_session_percentage": 0,
    "telegram_sessions": 0,
    "whatsapp_chat_aht": "29:27:04",
    "whatsapp_chat_queue": 0,
    "whatsapp_chat_tm1r": "01:02:52",
    "whatsapp_chat_tmr": "01:05:59",
    "whatsapp_current_chats": 0,
    "whatsapp_finished_session_percentage": 100,
    "whatsapp_sessions": 18
  }
]
```

the way I managed to do it was creating a new array of objects receiving these values and separating by each type

example :

```
[
   {
     Whatsapp...
   }

   {
     telegram...
   }
]
```

and if the index was equal to 0 I would return whatsapp if not I would return the current index

but I don't think that would be the best way to do it.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many ways to iterate through array. you can use map method but it will be costly due to it will create a new array.

```
array.map((element) => { /* your function */ })
```

or you can use forEach Method it

```
array.forEach((element) => { /* your function */ })
```

If you are asking about the different key value than just create a new array and Push the element into the new array.

```
const newarray = [];
array.forEach((element) => { newarray.push(element)})
```

It will store all the value with key name and the value with index of 0 to Last-value in object-array
For Populating Array https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/4-ways-to-populate-an-array-in-javascript-836952aea79f

Comment: I need to show the data from de array and I can't use map because the keys are different

I think I need to create new array and organize that I think